# The number of tries never increments by more than one in Python - help please?

Tags: python

Whenever it takes me several tries to beat the game, it always says the number_of_guesses is 1, which isn't true. What have I done wrong?

My code:

```
import random

print("Welcome to Rock, Paper, Scissors. \nYou will be going up against the computer, who will randomly",
  "choose an object to duel you with!")

user_win = False

while not user_win:

    user_guess = input("\nChoose either Rock, Paper or Scissors: ")
    user_guess = user_guess.lower()

    if user_guess != "rock" and user_guess != "paper" and user_guess != "scissors":
        print("You didn't enter a valid guess. Try again, please.")
        user_guess = input("\nChoose either Rock, Paper or Scissors: ")
        user_guess = user_guess.lower()

    computer_guess = random.randint(1,3)

    if computer_guess == 1:
        computer_guess = "rock"
    elif computer_guess == 2:
        computer_guess = "paper"
    else:
        computer_guess = "scissors"

    print("Your guess:", user_guess.capitalize(), "\nComputer guess:", computer_guess.capitalize())

    number_of_guesses = 1

    if user_guess == computer_guess:
        print("\nThe game is a tie. You guessed", user_guess, "and so did the computer.")
        number_of_guesses += 1
        user_win = False
    elif (user_guess == "rock" and computer_guess == "scissors") or (user_guess == "paper" and computer_guess == "rock"):
        print("\nCongratulations! You have beaten the computer by playing", user_guess.capitalize(), "while the computer played", computer_guess.capitalize())
        user_win = True
        number_of_guesses += 1
    else:
        print("\nDamn! The computer won by playing", computer_guess.capitalize(), "while you played", user_guess.capitalize())
        user_win = False
        number_of_guesses += 1

if number_of_guesses == 1:
    print("\nYou won, and it only took you %d try!" % number_of_guesses)
else:
    print("\nYou won, and it only took you %d tries!" % number_of_guesses)

input("\nPress enter to exit the program.")
```

I think that's formatted correctly. It's not easy to put code in here. Thank you!

Comment: just try to print where ever you are changing `user_win` and you'll know where you are going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are always setting numbers of guesses equal to 1 inside your loop:

```
 print("Your guess:", user_guess.capitalize(), "\nComputer guess:", computer_guess.capitalize())

 number_of_guesses = 1 # setting here
```

Set `the number_of_guesses` outside the while loop

Answer (score 1):

First of all in the while loop you always initialize `number_of_guesses = 1` on every run. That is why this will always be 1 in each run.

Take this initialization before the while.